# Configuring charset for decoding query parameters in WebLogic

Tags: java, http, servlets, weblogic12c

I have an encoding problem in my servlets.

I call my servlet like this:

```
http://myserver.com/myapp/myservlet?p=%d6
```

`%d6` is the encoded value for `Ö`.

In my servlet I do the following:

```java
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    String s = request.getCharacterEncoding();  // Returns null

    //request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); // If I uncomment this line, p will be Ö.
    String p = request.getParameter("p"); // Returns ý

    ...
```

I want to set the character encoding via the configuration and not via code.

I have tried the following in `weblogic.xml`, but it had no effect in this case:

```xml
<charset-params>
    <input-charset>
        <resource-path>*</resource-path>
        <java-charset-name>ISO-8859-1</java-charset-name>
    </input-charset>
</charset-params>
```

How do I configure WebLogic to use the encoding `ISO-8859-1` for `request.getParameter`?

Comment: The world decided to standardize URLs to use utf8 encoding somwhere around 2005. Think twice before you do this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `weblogic.xml`, try the following:

```xml
<charset-params>
    <input-charset>
        <resource-path>/*</resource-path>
        <java-charset-name>ISO8859_1</java-charset-name>
    </input-charset>
</charset-params>
```

That is, use `ISO8859_1` instead of `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: Had the same problem and this answer nailed it. Curiously enough setting `<webapp.encoding.default>` to `ISO8859_1` in an `<application-param>` in [weblogic-application.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/app_xml.htm#r6c1-t2) didn't work, even setting `<webapp.encoding.usevmdefault>` to `false`. Any hint why?